# Liferay.Service.register is not a function?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, liferay-service-builder

I am trying to call this javascript method:

```
Liferay.Service.register("Liferay.Service.myservice", "de.package.service", "my-portlet");
```

But all I get is this error:

```
Liferay.Service.register is not a function.
 (In 'Liferay.Service.register("Liferay.Service.myservice", "de.package.service", "my-portlet")', 'Liferay.Service.register' is undefined)
```

Honestly ... I have no idea why this is happening.
Could anyone help me out here ?

Comment: You should add why you try to call this method - I guess you have read them in a Tutorial somewhere? And I guess you are using Liferay 6.2? A search for _Liferay 6.2 "Liferay.service.register"_ would reveal [this forum post](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/43849188).

Comment: Which  Liferay version are you using? Have you created a portlet service plugin , this code is automatically generated when you run service builder. Could you please add some more info about your portlet.xml , liferay-portlet.xml ,jsp  and js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, here is the answer:

forget about Liferay.register and all that other Liferay. stuff.
Use async json webservices instead.

works like a charm :)